# Gnuplot: How to disable "WARNING: Plotting with an 'unknown' terminal."?

Tags: gnuplot, suppress-warnings

In a Gnuplot file, I am using the following "subroutine" file to compute dimensions of some table:

```bash
# Sets:
# size_x ,min_x, max_x,
# size_y, min_y, max_y.

# Dummy plot to get statistical properties without
# having "stats" command like with v4.4.4.

set terminal unknown
# Works with v4.4
# if ($# == 1) plot $0 using 1:2; else plot $0 using $1

# Works with v5.5
if (ARGC == 1) plot ARG1 using 1:2; else plot ARG1 using @ARG2

min_x = GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN
max_x = GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX
min_y = GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN
max_y = GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX

size_x = max_x - min_x
size_y = max_y - min_y
```

so there is a deliberate `set terminal unknown` because the script is not suposed to display anything, but only to compute some values.

I tried `set terminal` in a Gnuplot prompt, but it seems there is no dummy or null terminal...

Is there a way to get rid of that message?

I am currently using Gnuplot v5.4.2.

Comment: I use "set terminal dumb" sometimes. It makes an ascii plot that doesn't mean much but its fast and sets the replot and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use gnuplot 5.4.2 (actually gnuplot>=4.6.0, March 2012) then simply do it with `stats` (which was not available in v4.4.). Check `help stats` and type `show var STATS` in the gnuplot console to see the parameters which are calculated.

```
stats "myFile.dat" u 1:2 nooutput

size_x = STATS_max_x - STATS_min_x
size_y = STATS_max_y - STATS_min_y

print size_x, size_y
```

Comment: Than you. That works.